# How to count the nth consecutive instance of a word in a list in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get the row number containing yet another instance of a word in a column, where n is a predefined constant, e.g. 5.

The closest result to the one I wanted (even if obtained indirectly), is the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A1:A",J9))="pear")*(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("W4:W",J9))<INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("X4:X",J9))))
```

in which I use the INDIRECT () function to generalize the row number of interest, but the data must be updated manually in the cell taken as reference (J9 in the example) every time the list changes, which is not the best (although better than manually changing the line number for every single formula that uses it!).

The list is made up of repeated words (there may be empty cells at the end, not in the middle), like the following:

```
      A
   _______
1  orange
2  apple
3  apple
4  pear
5  pineapple
6  orange
7  pear
8  apple
   .....
```

The expected result for n=2 and "pear" as a word to search for would be 7. Is it possible to do something like this in excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="pear"),2)
```

Change the `"pear"` to the cell which has the value desired and the `2` at the end to the cell which has which ordinal wanted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. And integrating it with the formula above, we obtain =SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A1:A",AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="pear"),2)))="pear")*(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("W4:W",AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="pear"),2)))<INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("X4:X",AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="pear"),2))))), which is a punch in the eye but lets us to forget about the extra J cell. Now it's really just copy and paste data!

Comment: @Rokuros1080 if you want to test the value in W where the second pear is against the value in x then we just need two indexes:  `=INDEX(W:W,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="pear"),2))<INDEX(X:X,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))="pear"),2))`

Comment: That formula should find the intersection of all cells that meet the search criteria, but how would I extract the data on which to do the calculations? Be patient, but my level of knowledge of excel like my english, as you may have understood, is very elementary. I am much more comfortable with C # (which is why I claim to have perhaps overly sophisticated functions on a spreadsheet!).

Comment: ask a new question that shows what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Locate(rng As Range, valu As String, times As Long) As Long
    Dim kount As Long, r As Range
    kount = 0
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = valu Then
            kount = kount + 1
            If kount = times Then
                Locate = r.Row
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=Locate(A1:A100,"pear",2)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Macros must be enabled for this to work!